# Is there an advantage to using separate IPv4 and IPv6 reverse delegation servers?

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, rdns

Currently, we have the following DNS servers setup for reverse DNS of IPv4 and IPv6 ranges:

```
rdns0.v4.rdns
rdns1.v4.rdns
rdns2.v4.rdns
rdns0.v6.rdns
rdns1.v6.rdns
rdns2.v6.rdns
```

Where the `v4` servers are used only for reverse DNS zones for IPv4 and the `v6` servers are used only for IPv6 reverse DNS zones.

Upon a partly reconstruction of the network, I'm just wondering if there are any advantages to using separate IPv4 and IPv6 DNS servers.

Comment: Is `.rdns` a real TLD somewhere, or did you just make it up? That said, no, I don't think I've ever seen that sort of v4/v6 separation, nor can I imagine why it would be useful.

Comment: I removed the last part so it's not an FQDN.

Comment: @grawity If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.